# How can I read RDD in my java program from a file that was created by Python program

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, rdd

I have a python Spark program that creates features from raw data and stores them into a Pickle file using the `saveAsPickleFile` method. I can also use `saveAsTextFile` method.

The other program is written in Java implementing a classifier using ML.

Is it possible to read the serialized pickle file into an RDDs in Java?

Comment: Can someone explain why are you giving me negative feedbacks? I a lot of time searching for the answer before I submitted this question? If you know the answer, know where I can find it, etc. Please let me know. Giving negative feedback is not productive. I asked this question to get help not to get put down!

Comment: I don't know, why people are down-voting - your question seems legitimate to me. I'm not familiar with python or pickle files, but if you use `saveAsTextFile` instead, reading it in Java afterwards is straight forward using `sc.textFile("/path/to/your/file")`

Comment: I agree with @GlennieHellesSindholt. Concerning pickle files, even thought there is frameworks that allows reading Pickle objects, you might consider using textFiles instead as the solution is more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

- `saveAsPickleFile` is using standard `pickle` module. It is possible to read object serialized using `pickle` for example using Jython `pickle` but it is far from straightforward
- `saveAsTextFile` creates a plain text file. There is nor reason why it couldn't be loaded in Java. Problem is you still have to parse the content. PySpark version of `saveAsTextFile` is simply using `unicode` method which doesn't have to return any meaningful representation. If you want something that can be easily loaded it is a good idea to manually create string representation
- for key-value the simplest thing is to use `saveAsSequenceFile` / `sequenceFile`:

  ```py
  rdd = sc.parallelize([(1L, "foo"), (2L, "bar")])
  rdd.saveAsSequenceFile("pairs")
  ```

  ```scala
  sc.sequenceFile[Long, String]("pairs").collect()
  // Array[(Long, String)] = Array((2,bar), (1,foo))
  ```
- if you have more complex data you can use Parquet files:

  ```py
  from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector

  rdd = sc.parallelize([
      (1L, DenseVector([1, 2])), (2L, DenseVector([3, 4]))])
  rdd.toDF().write.parquet("pairs_parquet")
  ```

  ```scala
  sqlContext.read.parquet("pairs_parquet").rdd.collect()
  // Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([2,[3.0,4.0]], [1,[1.0,2.0]])
  ```
- [Avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) or even simple JSON could be a viable solution as well.